# Find the mathematical expectation

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expectation

> Find the expectation of
>
> $$f(x) = a(1+x)^{-(1+a)}, \quad x>0.$$

The answer given is $\frac{1}{a-1}$.

I am not getting the answer. Please help.

Comment: I think you mean the expectation of a random variable with density $f(x)$

Comment: Hint: $x=1+x-1$ hence, for every $a>1$, $$E(X)=\int_0^\infty xf(x)dx=a\int_0^\infty(1+x)^{-a}dx-a\int_0^\infty(1+x)^{-a-1}dx=a\cdot\frac1{a-1}-a\cdot\frac1a=\ldots$$ For $0<a\leqslant1$, $E(X)$ is infinite.

Comment: OP: Do you realize you accepted an answer predicting a *negative* expectation for a random variable always *positive*?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is simply an integration problem. The average value can be written as
$$<x>=\int_{0}^{\infty}xf(x)dx=a\int_{0}^{\infty}x(1+x)^{-(1+a)}dx$$
you can integrate by parts, calling $u=x$ and $dv=(1+x)^{-(1+a)}$, finding
$$<x>=\int_{0}^{\infty}xf(x)dx=\left.-(1+a)^{-a}x\right|_{0}^{\infty}+\int_{0}^{\infty}(1+x)^{-a}dx=\frac{-1}{1-a}$$
considering $a>1$ (otherwise the function do not converge)

**Edit**: After looking at Did's comment, I have realized that there was wrong sign mistake in the answer: a positive variable can never have a negative expectation value

Comment: Please refer to my comment for a more accurate result.

Comment: @Did I don't see in your comment why do you say that the integral for $a>1$ do not converge

Comment: ?? Are you engaged in some sort of damage control? Then, without me.

Comment: @Did I am not engaged with anything. I was just wondering if you though there was a mistake in my answer (and in fact there is one!) and I've misunderstood your question (sorry for that, I was thinking you were referring to the range of $a$). Thank you for the remark, I will correct the answer and add the reference to your comment

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a random variable with density $f(x)$, then $$E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x) dx = a\int_0^\infty x(1+x)^{-(1+a)}$$

First of all, this converges only if $a > 1$

Then the integral can be done fairly easily with the substitution $ u = x +1$, unless I'm mistaken